# Implementing a CNN with one convolution layer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I am trying to implement a 1 channel CNN by slightly changing this article: [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.5882v2.pdf).
The problem is that I am new to keras and deep learning and I don't know this far why I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 100 from 1 for 'conv2d_1/convolution' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,1,70,100], [100,100,100,64]
```

Obviously, it's a mismatch in the dimensions.

I am using this code code:

```
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Reshape
import pdb
Vocab_Size=11123
MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH=70
EMBED_DIM=100
model = Sequential()
embed1=Embedding(Vocab_Size+1,EMBED_DIM,input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,input_shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,EMBED_DIM,1))
nb_labels=6
model = Sequential()
model.add(embed1)
model.add(Reshape((1,MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH, EMBED_DIM)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, strides=5, kernel_size=EMBED_DIM, activation="relu", padding='valid'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH-5+1,1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(len(nb_labels), activation="softmax"))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                optimizer='rmsprop',
                metrics=['acc'])
```

Edit1:
I updated as mentionned by Media padding to same.
Now I have another problem for the next layer:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 66 from 1 for 'max_pooling2d_1/MaxPool' (op: 'MaxPool') with input shapes: [?,1,14,64].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should change the following line to solve the problem:

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, strides=5, kernel_size=EMBED_DIM, activation="relu", padding='valid'))
```

instead use this code:

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, strides=5, kernel_size=EMBED_DIM, activation="relu", padding='same'))
```

this will keep the dimension of your input. If it does not work, let me know to help you more.

Comment: It worked Thanks! but now I have now another problem.Please have a look below!

Comment: I solved the problem by applying also padding='same'

Comment: Did you solve it? because I did not understand what you meant :)

Comment: Yes. I got the same error with maxpooling layer. I solved exactly with the same method.